# Is it easy to hide magic settlements in the modern world?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

To my understanding, many magical folk live in separate physical communities from Muggles. Considering how fast Muggles are spreading, is it still easy to hide magical habitations? A place like Hogwarts can be disguised as a ruined abandoned castle to the naked Muggle eye but the Muggle can still walk up to it. Spells can help a magical village, for example, disguise itself from a Muggle passerby, but can said passerby walk through without ever realising something is amiss while magical folk continue to go about their lives as opposed to hiding away whenever a Muggle is near?

Comment: You just make them unplottable. There doesn't seem to be any size restriction given that an entire wizarding town is covered. Note though, that there's only one wizard-only town in the whole of the UK and it seems to be relatively remote.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Hogsmeade is mentioned as being one of the last (or is it just the last?) entirely magical communities within the UK. Most magical people live in communities that also contain Muggles, so they generally wouldn't need to hide an entire village or town.

Comment: The best answer is: We're going to find out. While the Current HP universe we know is well-integrated into the British populace, JKR has revealed that the American wizarding world is specifically Jingoist & xenophobic to the Muggle world. It helps that the Americas are MASSIVE, landmass-wise, in comparison to Europe, but there's going to be some overlap. So we'll get an answer to this much more in Fantastic Beasts.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

For example...

### They can be made Unplottable, so that even if someone finds them, they can't give graphical directions.

> So Durmstrang’ll just look like a ruin to an outsider too?”
>
> “Maybe,” said Hermione, shrugging, “or it might have Muggle-repelling
>   charms on it, like the World Cup stadium. And to keep foreign
>   wizards from finding it, they’ll have made it Unplottable —”
>
> “Come again?”
>
> “Well, you can enchant a building so it’s impossible to plot on a
>   map, can’t you?”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

This also mentions several other methods of concealment.

### Muggle-repelling charms

Wizards can make it difficult or impossible for non-magical types to approach such a building.

> “Seats a hundred thousand,” said Mr. Weasley, spotting the awestruck
>   look on Harry’s face. “Ministry task force of five hundred have been
>   working on it all year. Muggle Repelling Charms on every inch of it.
>   Every time Muggles have got anywhere near here all year, they’ve
>   suddenly remembered urgent appointments and had to dash away again . .
>   . bless them,” he added fondly, leading the way toward the nearest
>   entrance, which was already surrounded by a swarm of shouting witches
>   and wizards.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

So this would make discovery very difficult.

### They can be disguised

> “Just you, then,” said Ron. “So go on — how d’you hide a place
>   like Hogwarts?”
>
> “It’s bewitched,” said Hermione. “If a Muggle looks at it, all they
>   see is a moldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying
>   danger, do not enter, unsafe.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

There are many other mechanisms, such as Memory Charms, Fidelius Charms, and various others that can help conceal the existence of wizarding buildings. The primary component, though, appears to be that in the Potterverse, both wizards and Muggles are considerably less interested in the other than would likely be the case in our world. (Someone should write a fanfic).

Comment: "both wizards and Muggles are considerably less interested in the other" and somehow they keep making babies with each other, lol

Comment: how is babby formed? how girl get pragnent?

Comment: Let's not talk about how magic can make life "fun" in that regard